# Overlapping score between two bb

Tags: c++, overlap, bounding-box

I am trying to create a function that calculates the intersection ratio between two bounding boxes. I have Rect information about two rectangles. I have created a intersection function which returns a double score of intersection between two boxes:

```
double Detection::overlapBB(Rect a, Rect b){

int xa1 = a.x; int xa2 = a.x + a.width;
int ya1 = a.y; int ya2 = a.y + a.height;
int xb1 = b.x; int xb2 = b.x + b.width;
int yb1 = b.y; int yb2 = b.y + b.height;

cout << "The first rectangle:("<< xa1 << "," <<ya1 <<"),(" <<xa2<<"," <<ya2 <<")" <<endl;
cout << "The second rectangle:("<< xb1 << "," <<yb1 <<"),(" <<xb2<<"," <<yb2 <<")" <<endl;


int surfaceA = a.width*a.height;
int surfaceB = b.width*b.height;

int xn1 = Max(xa1, xb1); int yn1 = Max(ya1, yb1);
int xn2 = Min(xa2, xb2); int yn2 = Min(ya2, yb2);

 cout << "The second rectangle:("<< xn1 << "," <<yn1 <<"),(" <<xn2<<"," <<yn2 <<")" <<endl;

//int SI = (xn2 - xn1)*(yn2-yn1);
int SI = Max(0, Max(xa2, xb2) - Min(xa1, xb1)) * Max(0, Max(ya2, yb2) - Min(ya1, yb1));
int SU = surfaceA +surfaceB - SI;

cout << SI << " " <<SU << " " <<surfaceA<< " " <<surfaceB << endl;

double intersection = ((double)SI/(double)SU);


return intersection;

}
```

I ve noticed that the returned variable is not true, when one rectangle is inside the other.    May I create statements for both case of complete overlapping and partial overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

Fere Res check this paradigm [intersection detection](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/teaching/rtr&3dgp/notes/intersection.pdf).